# How to compare two char arrays and display the different char?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I want to compare two char arrays and I want (if they are not equal) the different char to be desplayed on the output. For exemple, in my code below, the different char is "y". So on the output, I want to be written: "the different char is y, it is in the array ay but not in the ar". I am working with C# and here is the code that I have wrote, I am getting an error with the CompareTo method. Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.
NB, I am still a beginner.

```
     char[] ar = { 'a', 'h', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
     char[] ay = { 'a', 'y', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
     if (ar.SequenceEqual(ay))
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
     }
     else
     {
        Console.WriteLine("failure");
        char diff = ar.CompareTo((Object)ay));
        Console.Write(diff);
      }
```

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: I'm not sure what your requirements are but you could do this with some for or for each loops. For each difference store the different character in a separate array. After the looping completes loop through the array containing the differences and output the results

Comment: You can test for equal like this : if(string.Join("", ar) == string.Join("",ay)),  To get all differences you need to use Left  Outer Join which gives items in 2nd list that isn't in first list.  See : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Sami, here it is: "char[]' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'char[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Except method you can achieve this pretty simple, and you don't have to compare the arrays twice.

```
char[] ar = { 'a', 'h', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
char[] ay = { 'a', 'y', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
var different = ar.Except(ay).ToList();
if (different.Count == 0)
{
         Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
         foreach (char c in different)
         {
               Console.WriteLine(c);
         }
}
Console.WriteLine("Percent of similarity: "+(100-different.Count*100/ar.Length) +"%");
```

Comment: Thanks! But on the 4th ligne, "different.Count == 0" didn't worked.

Comment: Wonderful! Yep, it did worked now. I would like to add the percentage of similarity between those two arrays. So if the total of different char is equal to 2 for exemple and the array is 5 char, then the programe calculate the percentage. Did you understand me?

Comment: Yes, and i can easily do this, let me update my answer a second

Comment: I am a new user of stackoverflow, I didn't knew about this option. But I did it now.

Comment: No problem, you will get used with it

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this;

```
        char[] ar = { 'a', 'h', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
        char[] ay = { 'a', 'y', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
        List<char> matches = new List<char>();

        if (ar.SequenceEqual(ay))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ar.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (ar[i] != ay[i])
                {
                    matches.Add(ay[i]);
                }
            }
            foreach (var matched in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + matched);
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's worked very nicely. Thanks. I want only to be displayed on the output the percentage of similarity between those two arrays. For exemple, if there are 2 char different and the array contain 5 char, I want from the program to calculate the percentage of similarity between those arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option, I also added an extra char to the array just for the failure check:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] ar = { 'a', 'h', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
            char[] ay = { 'a', 'y', 'f', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
            Console.WriteLine(GetDiffOfCharArray(ay, ar, "ay", "ar"));
            ay = new char[] { 'a', 'h', 'm', 'a', 'd' };
            Console.WriteLine(GetDiffOfCharArray(ay, ar, "ay", "ar"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string GetDiffOfCharArray(char[] array1Values, char[] array2Values, string array1Name, string array2Name)
        {
            string result = "";

            if (array1Values.SequenceEqual(array2Values))
            {
                result = string.Format("Success, Array '{0}' matches Array '{1}'", array1Name, array2Name);
            }
            else
            {
                var diff = array1Values.Except(array2Values);
                result = string.Format("Failure, the different char is '{0}', it is in the array '{1}' but not in the array '{2}'", 
                    string.Join("','", diff), 
                    array1Name, 
                    array1Name);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the output for failure and success are as follows:

> Failure, the different char is 'y','f', it is in the array 'ay' but not in the array 'ay
>
> Success, Array 'ay' matches Array 'ar'

Comment: Very nice. But it appears on the output Failure and Success message in the same time.

Comment: thats cause I'm running one example where it fails and one example where its a success

Answer (score 0):

Ayman, Except can do trick for you. here is the code.

```
IEnumerable<char> inArArray = ar.Except(ay);
foreach (char c in inArArray) {
             Console.WriteLine("{0} Exists in ar but not in ay",c);
}


IEnumerable<char> inAyrray = ay.Except(ar);
foreach (char c in inAyrray)
{
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exists in ay but not in ar", c);
}
```